# Xamarin UITest Query How to get just the label as response

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

When I query my listview with automation Id in the Repl() window I get back a chunk of data. I only want back one field 'Text' or 'Label'

**here is my query:**
app.Query(q => q.Id("officerList").Descendant().Id("officerName").Index(0).Class("UILabel").Index(0))

**here is the return:**                                                   [                                                                                   [0] {
        Id => null,
        Description => ">",
        Rect => {
            Width => 88,
            Height => 20.5,
            X => 12,
            Y => 144,
            CenterX => 56,
            CenterY => 154.25
        },
        Label => "Abril, Jill M.",
        Text => "Abril, Jill M.",
        Class => "UILabel",
        Enabled => true
    }
]

**I want to continue the query and return only "Abril, Jill M."**

I tried adding .Label no luck it broke with error:
**(1,103): error CS1061: Type `Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery' does not contain a definition for`Label' and no extension method `Label' of type`Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference**

Comment: Did you try adding `.Text` ?

Comment: I tried that too - no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var query = app.Query(q => q.Id("officerList")
            .Descendant().Id("officerName")
            .Index(0).Class("UILabel")
            .Index(0));

var labelText = query[0]?.Text;
```

`labelText` should contain the value of the label you want.

In resume, the `Query` returns an Array of `AppResult` (AppResult[]). You need to get the item you want which is this case is the first item.

Hope this helps.-

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query also for Label - 
q.Id("officerList").Descendant().Id("officerName").Index(0).Class("UILabel").Index(0)).Label

Output -  "Abril, Jill M.", ,

OR For Text

q.Id("officerList").Descendant().Id("officerName").Index(0).Class("UILabel").Index(0)).first.text

Output -  "Abril, Jill M."

May be this would work